# $('.class').on('click', function(){ nach Ajax request works just one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm doing an Ajax request that gathers information off a database and posts it via .html on the site. Whithin this request there is a link with a class. When I click on this link a jquery function runs but it just works once.
Anyone knows how to solve this?

Ditte Lund

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. If you want that we help you then please give some code.

Comment: Check your console. You probably have an script error (JS fails silently...). If that doesn't work, you should consider posting some actual code (JSFiddle) ;)